# Justify uniform density of ideal gas at thermal equilbrium

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I'm trying to convince myself that an ideal gas in an arbitrarily-shaped, zero-gravity, closed container has uniform density in space at thermal equilibrium, where I define an ideal gas to consist of many point-like particles that only interact via elastic collisions.

I thought about using the Boltzmann distribution on one of the particles: the probability of a particle being within $(x,y,z) \leq \textbf{x} \leq (x+dx, y+dy, z+dz)$, denoted by $P(\textbf{x})dxdydz$, is
$$P(\textbf{x})dxydyz \propto \int e^{-E(\textbf{x}, \textbf{p})/k_BT} d\textbf{p}^3 = \int e^{-p^2/2mk_BT} d\textbf{p}^3.$$
So the statement of uniform density is equivalent to saying the above momentum integral is independent of position. It seems intuitive, but I'm not sure how to rigorously show that. How do I continue from here?

Comment: I mean, you are basically already there. There is no $x$ in your last integral. $p$ and $x$ are independant coordinates and $m$, $k_B$ and $T$ clearly don't depend on $x$ so there is nowhere for an $x$ dependence to be hiding

Comment: @BySymmetry Right, so I think my question then is how do we know $p$ and $x$ are independent?

Comment: Oh wait I get it because the momentum integral is over all possible momentums which doesn't depend on position. Thanks!